# .htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am getting Internal server error due to .htaccess.

My code is below

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and error_log file show]

```
/home/adonwayc/public_html/billing/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
[Tue Jan 06 14:43:58.213270 2015] [core:alert] [pid 642720] [client 122.177.194.19:60610] /home/adonwayc/public_html/billing/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
[Tue Jan 06 14:39:28.780669 2015] [core:alert] [pid 583314] [client 122.177.194.19:57750] /home/adonwayc/public_html/billing/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
[Tue Jan 06 14:39:28.780603 2015] [core:alert] [pid 583314] [client 122.177.194.19:57750] /home/adonwayc/public_html/billing/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /home/adonwayc/public_html/billing/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one
>   argument, the base URL of the per-directory context

Looking at the logs, your htaccess seems to be located in `billing` subfolder.
Your `RewriteBase` should then be `/billing/`.

Also, `REQUEST_URI` begins with a leading slash `/`.
Here is a corrected version of your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /billing/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:system|application) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```